# How to use SVG tag in google maps as marker instead of loading svg in img tag with the icon url prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, svg, google-maps-markers

I wanted to use the complete svg tag instead of img tag to load the marker on the google map,

this is not something new requirement or not possible thing because I have the reference webs which are having this concept but I don't see any options or possibilities in google map documentation or any StackOverflow answers.

Please visit the below website for the reference, Please inspect the element and see how they have used markers. The same was I wanted to use it, so could anyone please tell me how can I use svg in google map(Not loaded as img src, or no path notation because I want to place svg which has a hover event and deep path notation **) 
[vwn website](https://www.volkswagen-nutzfahrzeuge.de/app/dccsearch/vwn-de/de/Volkswagen%20Nutzfahrzeuge%20H%C3%A4ndlersuche/+/52.55835/13.49248/11/Autohaus%20M%C3%B6bus%20GmbH/+/+/+%20%20%20https://www.airbnb.com/s/berlin/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=unknown&ne_lat=65.21489877883494&ne_lng=42.27405677308684&sw_lat=29.90652298460648&sw_lng=-21.09508385191316&zoom=4&search_by_map=true&query=berlin)
[airbnb website](http://%20https://www.airbnb.com/s/berlin/homes?tab_id=home_tab&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&source=structured_search_input_header&search_type=unknown&ne_lat=65.21489877883494&ne_lng=42.27405677308684&sw_lat=29.90652298460648&sw_lng=-21.09508385191316&zoom=4&search_by_map=true&query=berlin)

```
const markerIcon = {
      url: 'images/google-map/GoogleMapPin.svg',
      scaledSize: new window['google'].maps.Size(50, 50)
    };

 const markers: any = markersData.map((link: any, index: any) => {
      const markerOption = {
        map,
        position: link,
        title: link.title,
        icon: markerIcon,
        height: 100
      };

      const marker = new window['google'].maps.Marker(markerOption);
  return marker;
});
```

Please follow the jsfiddle where the png file is used as icon, but I want to use svg file in svg tag only.

http://jsfiddle.net/86Ejf/945/

Please let me know if you have any questions, thanks in advance

Comment: You might wanna look into using Symbols. These are useful when you want to use a vector-based icon on a marker, or add an image to a polyline. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols#add_to_marker

Comment: @MervinSamy thanks for the suggestion, but if you look here in the example, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom

and please inspect the element and see how the yellow star is loaded, !! at the end it becomes png image and loaded in image tag.. but I would like to use the marker as SVG tag. for example, you could inspect the marker icon of the Airbnb or Volkswagen web. I have given the links to the questions.